# Работа с объектами после JSON parse

Tags: javascript, json, строки, дата

Всем привет. Есть такой код:

```
class User {
    constructor(id, username, date){
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.date= date;
    }
}

let myUsers = [
    new User(1, 'Mark', new Date('03.01.2016')),
    new User(2, 'Jacob', new Date('02.02.2016')),
    new User(3, 'Petr', new Date('01.02.2016'))
];
```

Я превращаю этот массив в JSON и храню в локальном хранилище.

```
localStorage.setItem('myUsers', JSON.stringify(myUsers));
```

Затем достаю и выполняю парсинг

```
let users = localStorage.getItem('myUsers');
users = JSON.parse(users);
```

Когда я пытаюсь вывести отформатированную дату

```
users.forEach(function(user){
  console.log(user.date.getDate());
});
```

сообщает об ошибке

```
Uncaught TypeError: user.date.getDate is not a function
```

Я так понимаю это происходит потому что после парсинга я получаю строку, а не объект с датой.
Собственно в этом и вопрос. Как получить возможность работать со свойствами объекта в данном случае?

Comment: вы видимо почему-то думаете, что при вызове `JSON.parse()` получите экземпляры объектов класса `User`, но это не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) Функции не являются допустимыми данными в JSON, так что они не будут работать. Кроме того, некоторые объекты, например, объект Date, станут строками после применения JSON.parse().

`JSON.stringify(myUsers)` создаст JSON-строку, которая будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
"[{"id":1,"username":"Mark","date":"2016-02-29T17:00:00.000Z"},{"id":2,"username":"Jacob","date":"2016-02-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"id":3,"username":"Petr","date":"2016-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"}]"
```

Т.е. у каждого объекта `User` будет сохранены свойста `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `object` и `array`. И после выполения `JSON.parse` вы получаете массив объектов `Object` (не `User`) с полями `id`, `username`, `date`.

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

Т.е. нужен метод для создания объектов User (что-то наподобии десериализации получится)

```
class User {
  constructor(id, username, date){
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.date = date;
  }

  static fromJson(json) {
    var data = JSON.parse(json); // Парсим поля
    var date = new Date(data.date); // создает объект Date из строки
    return new User(data.id, data.username, date); // Создаем новый инстанс
  }
};

Пример использования:

const user1 = new User(1, 'Mark', new Date('03.01.2016'));
const serialize = JSON.stringify(user1); //.toJson();
const _user1 = User.fromJson(serialize);

console.log(_user1.date.getDate()); // 1
```

Для "сериализации" только нужных свойств, можно написать так же метод `toJson`, внутри которого уже вызывать `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1):

В [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) можно вторым параметром передать функцию, которая будет вызвана для каждой пары ключ-значение:

```
const dateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z$/;

function reviver(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "string" && dateFormat.test(value)) {
        return new Date(value);
    }

    return value;
}

const text = '{ "date": "2016-04-26T18:09:16Z" }';
const obj = JSON.parse(text, reviver);
```

[Источник](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/04/28/deserializing-json-strings-as-javascript-date-objects).

Или, если вы знаете как называется название свойства, в котором хранится дата, то можно просто проверять значение аргумента `key`.

Аналогично, вы можете трансформировать результаты разбора JSON в любой нужный вам объект.

Comment: тут вопрос скорее про десериализацию конкретного класса `User`, а не про парсинг даты из строки в `Date`

Comment: Тогда проще всего заново пройтись по результатам и создать нужные объекты через конструктор User: 
`JSON.parse(json).map(data => new User(data.id, data.username, new Date(data.date)))`